# setting differnet areas of form to be clickable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have a form that looks like this:

[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2351/huesaturation.jpg](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2351/huesaturation.jpg)

i need different areas to execute different code, just as if there were buttons. how do i set areas of the form to be clickable in vb.net?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the reasons for using this background image of a form rather than actually using a form with controls on it.

Comment: its difficult for me to make a form that looks like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're using a bunch of button controls, just add the right event handlers to the right buttons.
- If you're not using buttons, then you need to know the exact coordinates of every particular clickable component. From there you can add the Click event handler to the window itself, then handle the input based on the coordinates of the mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know the location and sizes of the areas, of course, and then use the form's Click event handler.  You'll need to use the location of the cursor at the time the click occurred and check to see which area it's in.

I'd start here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx